# django fullcalender refetching events not workig

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to implement a fullcalendar in django. All the functions are working fine, but the calendar doesn't get refreshed if I use refetchevents  or rerender events `calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`. If i reload the page the events are showing up, but i want to see the changes without reloading the page. Any idea why is it not working?

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from calend import models
from calend.views import *
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', calendar, name='calendar'),
    path('add_event/', add_event, name='add_event'),
    path('update/', update, name='update'),
    path('remove/', remove, name='remove'),
]
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Events
from django.http import JsonResponse

def calendar(request):
    all_events = Events.objects.all()
    context = {
        "events":all_events,
    }
    return render(request,'calendar.html',context)

def add_event(request):
    start = request.GET.get("start", None)
    end = request.GET.get("end", None)
    title = request.GET.get("title", None)
    event = Events(name=str(title), start=start, end=end)
    event.save()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def update(request):
    start = request.GET.get("start", None)
    end = request.GET.get("end", None)
    title = request.GET.get("title", None)
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
    event.start = start
    event.end = end
    event.name = title
    event.save()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)


def remove(request):
    id = request.GET.get("id", None)
    event = Events.objects.get(id=id)
    event.delete()
    data = {}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.0/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: [
                    {% for event in events %}
                        {
                            title: "{{ event.name}}",
                            start: '{{ event.start|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                            end: '{{ event.end|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                            id: '{{ event.id }}',
                        },
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                    var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
                    if (title) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/add_event',
                            data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {      
                                alert("Added Successfully");
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            },
                            failure: function (data) {
                                alert('There is a problem!!!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                eventResize: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/update',
                        data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'id': id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            calendar.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                            alert('Event Update');
                        },
                        failure: function (data) {
                            alert('There is a problem!!!');
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventDrop: function (event) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var title = event.title;
                    var id = event.id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '/update',
                        data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end, 'id': id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('Event Update');
                        },
                        failure: function (data) {
                            alert('There is a problem!!!');
                        }
                    });
                },

                eventClick: function (event) {
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?")) {
                        var id = event.id;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: '/remove',
                            data: {'id': id},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                alert('Event Removed');
                            },
                            failure: function (data) {
                                alert('There is a problem!!!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },

            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br/>
<h2 align="center"><a href="#">title</a></h2>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the calendar doesn't get refreshed if I use refetchevents"...that's because as far as fullCalendar is concerned, your data source is a static array. (Look at the source code of your page (using your browser's View Source feature) and you'll see that the events are hard-coded into the page.) There's no information it can use to go back to the server and ask for more data.

Comment: if you want refetching to work, you need a dynamic data source - i.e. you have to have a server endpoint which can return the events in JSON format, and you need to tell fullCalendar the URL of that endpoint, so it can make an AJAX request to that URL whenever it needs to fetch events. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed for details of this approach.

Comment: P.S. you appear to have included the CSS for fullCalendar 3.5 and the JS for fullCalendar 3.9. Mixing versions is not a good idea, it could cause bugs or graphical glitches. Ensuring you use consistent versions of included files is a basic check you should be making before running your code. Also why use an alpha version of bootstrap 4? The 4.x branch of bootstrap is up to 4.4 now! No need to use an unsupported alpha version of the code. (These things are unrelated to your question, I'm just pointing out obvious other mistakes.)